# Can one simple_form create instances of multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I got `simple_form` for `testrun` model with multiple checkboxes, that save an array of testcases in a model field

app/views/testruns/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @testrun do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :testcase, as: :check_boxes,
      collection: [["testcase1", :testcase1], ["testcase2", :testcase2], ... ]%>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

It works fine, but from now I need to create another model called `testcase`. After submitting form, besides creating a new `testrun` instance, I need to create `testcase` instances which depends on every flag checked.

Any idea how can I do it?

Comment: To which field of `Testcase` model you want to save the testcase? And what is the association between `Testrun` and `Testcase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `simple_fields_for`. Assuming you have `has_many :testcases` in `Testrun` and the field name of `Testcase` is `name`, the below steps should put you in the right direction.

```
#app/models/testrun.rb
accepts_nested_attributes_for :testcases

#app/controllers/testrun_controller.rb
def new
  @testrun = Testrun.new
  @testrun.testcases.build
end

private
def testrun_params
  params.require(:testrun).permit(:field1, :field2.., testcases_attrubtes: [name: []])
end

#app/views/testruns/_form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @testrun do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :testcases do |testcase| %>
    <%= testcase.input :name, as: :check_boxes,
      collection: [["testcase1", :testcase1], ["testcase2", :testcase2], ... ]%>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you so much! that's exactly what i was looking for.